# Finding computed fields in Firebird 2.5

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5

Computed fields are readonly. I need to find all such fields in specific table.

This query solves this problem (returns info if column is computed or not):

```sql
select r.rdb$field_name, r.rdb$update_flag
from rdb$relation_fields r
where r.rdb$relation_name = 'specific_table'
```

At least it looks like it solves it, but it seems that returned informations are incorrect.

When `RDB$UPDATE_FLAG` is `0`, its computed (readonly). But its `0` even for normal columns.

Comment: [According to Dmitry Yemanov](https://sourceforge.net/p/firebird/mailman/message/37323005/), `RDB$UPDATE_FLAG` should be 1 for normal columns, but it is possible that in the past it wasn't populated correctly, and such information would survive backup and restores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted computed fields instead - that is what you have to query for, the expression used to compute.

> `RDB$FIELDS` stores definitions of columns and domains, both system and custom. This is where the detailed data attributes are stored for all columns.
>
> The column `RDB$FIELDS.RDB$FIELD_NAME` links to `RDB$RELATION_FIELDS.RDB$FIELD_SOURCE`
>
> `RDB$COMPUTED_BLR` - The binary language representation (BLR) of the SQL expression the database server uses for evaluation when accessing a `COMPUTED BY` column

https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref-appx04-fields

Hence, something like this should work:

```
select r.rdb$field_name --, r.rdb$update_flag
from rdb$relation_fields r, RDB$FIELDS f
where r.rdb$relation_name = 'specific_table'
  and f.RDB$FIELD_NAME = r.RDB$FIELD_SOURCE
  and f.RDB$COMPUTED_BLR is not NULL
```

P.S. https://github.com/FirebirdSQL/firebird-documentation/issues/157